# Can I binding datatype in Runtime?

Tags: c++

Suppose it exists a namespace Foo.

```
namespace Foo {
    T m;
    U n;
}
```

T and U may be int, double or other built-in type. So, is it possible that can determine built-in type in Runtime?

Comment: Type and runtime will only get together in C++ with the dynamic type of some object. Most of what you see about types in C++ is static, that is Nov existent at runtime.

Comment: Try using `typeid` operator

Comment: C++ is statically typed, but you can use a `union` with built-in types.

Comment: But I think you need type_traits

Comment: I'm not sure this question really makes sense to ask. Since `Foo`, `T`, `U` and such are all things that are already fixed at compile-time, trying to determine something about them at runtime seems pointless at best. This might be a case where you need to take a step back and ask a question about what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

No, C++ is statically typed. All types are known at compile time and cannot change at runtime.

Comment: Actually there are dynamic types in C++: Inherit from some polymorphic base to achieve that.

Comment: @DanielJour There's no intrinsic reflection mechanism though. This answer  is perfectly valid.

Comment: It is, at least for the purpose of answering the question. Though "all types are known at compile time" is technically not correct for C++.

Comment: @DanielJour Are you sure? I'm not very familiar with exact definitions in the standard, but a variable only has one type that is known at compile time. When using a polymorphic pointer you still have to cast and declare a new variable with a different type.

Comment: A variable has just a static type, that is right. But an instance of a class has also a (dynamic) type. So when you have an variable of type `Class &`, and `Class` or one of its bases are polymorphic, then the type of the instance referenced by the variable can only be known at run time (Could be `Class`, or any class deriving from it).